# How do promise chains work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, promise, angular-promise

I've found the following code in the SO and I try to debug it in order to better understand the promise concept ,Currently there is something that I was not understand in the code below which is why the last then are getting the value (in specificTweet) with id==4 and not all the tweets list ?

```
$.get('profile.json').then(function (profile) {

    return $.get('tweets.json').then(function (response) {
        return response.filter(function (tweet) {
            //this is return that not related to the promise just to the filter
            return tweet.id === 4;
        });
    });

}).then(function (specificTweet) {
```

...

This is the JSON file ,

```
[
  {
   "id": 1,
   "tweet": "OMG, worst day ever, my BF @BobbyBoo dumped me",
   "usersMentioned": [
     {
      "id": 10,
      "username": "BobbyBoo"
     }
    ]
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "tweet": "OMG, best day ever, my BF came back to me"
  },
  {
   "id": 3,
   "tweet": "OMG, worst day ever, just don't ask"
  },
  {
   "id": 4,
   "tweet": "@BobbyBoo OMG...just OMG!",
   "usersMentioned": [
     {
      "id": 10,
      "username": "BobbyBoo"
     }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a code like this:

```
doSomething().then(function (result1) {
    return 'foo';
}).then(function (result2) {
    console.log(result2 === 'foo');    // this logs "true" to the console
});
```

you're creating a promise chain. Each `.then()` creates a new promise that is either resolved when the original promise is resolved and when the success handler completes or rejected when the original promise is rejected and the failure handler completes. The new promise will "contain" data returned by the last success/failure handler. So because the success handler in the first `.then()` in the code sample returns the filtered tweets, the success handler in the second `.then()` (second `.then()` is called on the promise returned from the first `.then()`) will received that filtered list, not the original list.

You'd best just [see the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

However, there's a small mistake in the code sample. The second handler wouldn't receive just the specific tweet, it'd receive a list containing just that one tweet.

Answer (score 1):

Try to evaluate it the other way around, from bottom to top. The result of the below expression is always passed to the above expression when you chain `then` calls.

4.`.then(function (specificTweet)`

3.`return response.filter(function (tweet) {` -> filter tweets and pass result above

2.`return $.get('tweets.json').then(function (response)` -> pass tweets above

1.`$.get('profile.json')` -> pass profile to above